# Magento (ver. 1.7 / 1.8.1.0) built in Captcha on Front-end Custom Form

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, captcha, extensions

I am trying to add Magento (ver. 1.8.1.0) in-built Captcha on extension 'Ask A Question' but somehow it's not displaying on the front-end page tab:

[image]

(1) app/code/community/Unirgy/DropshipVendorAskQuestion/etc/config.xml

```
<default>
 <captcha>
     <frontend>
         <areas>
             <dcg_module_unique>
                 <label>Ask A Question</label>
             </dcg_module_unique>
         </areas>
     </frontend>
 </captcha>
 </default>

<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch_customer_post>
        <observers>
            <udqa>
                <class>udqa/observer</class>
                <method>checkCaptcha</method>
            </udqa>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch_customer_post>
    </events>
```

(2) app/code/community/Unirgy/DropshipVendorAskQuestion/Model/Observer.php

```
public function checkCaptcha($observer) {

    $formId = 'dcg_module_unique'; // Identifier in config.xml
    $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
    $request = $controller->getRequest();
    if ($captchaModel->isRequired()) {
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();

        $request->getPost(Mage_Captcha_Helper_Data::INPUT_NAME_FIELD_VALUE);
        if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->_getCaptchaString($request, $formId))) {


            if((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')) {
                // Is ajax
                $action = $request->getActionName();
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->setFlag(
                        $action, Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);

                $controller->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(200);
                $controller->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

                $controller->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode(
                        array(
                            "msg" => Mage::helper('module')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.')
                        )
                    ));

            } else {
               // Is form submit
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
                    ->addError(Mage::helper('module')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
                $controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
                    ->setCustomerFormData($controller->getRequest()->getPost());
                $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));
            }
        }
    }
  return $this;
}
```

(3) app/design/frontend/base/default/template/uqda/product/question.phtml

```
<li class="wide">
    Captcha :
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('captcha/captcha')
        ->setFormId('dcg_module_unique')
        ->setImgWidht(230)
        ->setImgHeight(50)
        ->toHtml();
    ?>
</li>
```

(4) app/design/frontend/base/default/template/uqda/product/tab.phtml

```
<?php

echo $this->getChildHtml('udqa.list');
echo $this->getChildHtml('udqa.qa');
echo $this->getChildHtml('captcha');

?>
```

I have followed this tutorial:
(1) http://mustakarhu.com/blog/magento-captcha-extension-ajax/

Any clues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I saw a similar behaviour when the media directory was not writeable. Did you check file permissions?